# Jquery Load Content Slide In/Out from Right

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to have on clicking menu items, the div will slide from right to left and on open the option to close (which slides back to the right)

eg: http://www.cortac.com/

Any idea, demo links etc. to accomplish this?

I found this which comes close to the above but does not slide from right to left.

http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/011_jQuerySite/sample/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - slide right to left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/jquery-slide-right-to-left)

Answer (score 2):

I made a very quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jaketoolson/ukztv/

I set the panel to absolute positioning with right set to a negative equal to width.

```
#page {
position: absolute;  
top: 20%;
right: -400px; 
width: 400px;
}
```

Then the jQuery is a mouseover (use click etc) effect with "animate" setting the target css:

```
$('.link').mouseover(function() {
$('#page').animate({'right':'0px'}, 1500);
}).mouseout(function(){
$('#page').animate({'right': '-800px'}, 1500);});
```

To get it to load pages, this can be done via AJAX or other methods.  See the example I'm currently building here: http://jaketoolson.com/ems/index.php

Comment: If you look at the jQuery on the EMS link I added, I have the "book" sliding out (open) when loaded and when you click anywhere OUTSIDE of the book, it slides in (closes).  Clicking on either of the 2 tags loads that page via AJAX and updates the tag css.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question 8 months ago, and figured out an answer ... a bit more complex than what you've asked, but its the only thing like it I've seen...

[best approach for jQuery slider with dynamic prev/next content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156870/best-approach-for-jquery-slider-with-dynamic-prev-next-content)